# How do i insert mysql query with single quote?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert query with single qoute `'`.its break my query . e.g

```
INSERT INTO news (`Id`, `UserId`, `description`) VALUES (1,12,'Hello this descriptrion  and this single qoute ' in sentance');
```

It dose not insert and give error. so my question is whenever user enter description with single qoute e.g `it's very hot today`. how can i handle  `'` 
 single quote in this way ?

You Answer highly Appreciate

Comment: From PHP you would use a prepared statement, then this will simply not be an issue: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that :

```
  INSERT INTO news (`Id`, `UserId`, `description`) VALUES (1,12,"Hello this descriptrion  and this single qoute ' in sentance");
```